# is there way to make "target = _blank " in defining results in struts.xml?

Tags: struts2

I have the following code in struts.xml and I want that the result for "success" will be in a new page, is there way to handle this in struts.xml?

```
<action name="deleteAccount" class = "com.sample.AccountMaintenanceAction" method="deleteAccount" >
<result name="success">/message.jsp</result>
<result name="input" >/accountMaintenance.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/accountMaintenance.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: New page is not a new window you should clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; you can't open a new window from the server side.

Nor would it seem reasonable to do so if you're just trying to display a response message: seems like it'd be better to make an Ajax request and process either a JSON or HTML response.